# Disable iTerm context menu popup

Tags: iterm

I am trying to cut and paste text but the iTerm popup keeps impeding me. This is due to `iTerm` and not generally on macOS since I have set the lower right corner as context-menu /right click but I'm dragging on the left side of the trackpad.

This behavior is happening regularly and is quite aggravating. Is there an way to disable the popup ?

Details:  I put one finger down, then the other and drag it.  But there is an annoying couple second delay and then the popup instead of selecting text.

[image]

Comment: What's your cut/paste method? I'm trying to figure out how that would invoke a right click.

Comment: i'll add details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is an advanced setting 'dictionary' lookup

[image]

I set it to `no`  . I am v skeptical of the decision to make this default to `yes` given how much aggravation it has been.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the Context Menu key on my external keyboard, were it was pulling up random commands from my history in iTerm2. Sometimes I would accidentally hit that key and it started to get annoying so I fixed it.

What I did was:

- go to the iTerm2 Settings window
- in the Keys tab > Press `+`
- Click `Click to Set`
- Press the Context Menu key
- Set it to `Ignore` > Click the `OK` button

Since your Paste shortcut is the Context Menu key + Right Click, maybe it will still work for you? I am curious now. Please let me know if you try it.

**My context:**
I only use a Mac for work and I am by no means an OSX expert.

Comment: Nice answer.  I'm not sure how to "press the Context Menu key".  I'm actually curious if such a key even exists by default in macOS: i need to use the trackpad to do it presently